# PHP Array Search Using External File for Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that I'm trying to use so users can search what zone they are in by their zip code. When I enter a zip code to test that matches one in the climate-zone-1.txt file it returns "Zip code not found", but when I echo the location of the number it shows.

Any ideas where its not recognizing the input?

```
<?php
$file = fopen("climate-zone-1.txt", "r");
$cz1 = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $cz1[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

echo $cz1[2] . "<br>";

$userinput = $_GET["zip"];

echo $userinput . "<br>";

echo "Climate zone: ";

if (in_array($userinput, $cz1)) {
    echo "Climate Zone 1" ;
}
else echo "Zip code not found."

?>
```

The code works perfectly when the arrays are built using PHP, however I have a lot of numbers to add to the array and using a txt file would be MUCH faster.

**FIX** Changing `$cz1[] = fgets($file);` to `$cz1[] = trim(fgets($file));` worked.

Comment: What does climate-zone-1.txt look like

Comment: Just a list of zip codes, one per line.

Comment: try changing `$cz1[] = fgets($file);` to `$cz1[] = trim(fgets($file));` ... you might have some extra whitespace after the zipcode lines

Comment: If you state it is much faster, then benchmark it to proof it .. I can already say that your statement is bogus .. You first load every line into an array, and then you compare just one value ..

Comment: Woo hoo! That worked! I went through and check the file twice and there wasn't any extra white space after the zipcode lines but maybe pressing return counts?

Comment: @user2458133 Might be difference in OS's...probably was a \r hanging arround at the end of each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `$cz1[] = fgets($file);` to `$cz1[] = trim(fgets($file));` worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.. you should use database for problems like this !

Now, your input from `$_GET` can have some characters, that are changed by URL input validation (like diacritics or spaces, that become %20).

Or your input file can have some spaces (or non-printable characters, like \r, \n...) around ZIP codes.

There cant be told much more, since you didnt provide a lot of information.

Comment: One step at a time. I'm not a master of PHP, just want to get something working to go off of first.

Comment: Also I have the form limiting responses to 5 numerical characters.